# How can I make a ContentPage with a StackLayout inside scrollable?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code I have:

```
<ContentPage>
   <ContentPage.Content>
       <StackLayout Spacing="10" Margin="20">
       <Label /> 
       <Label />
       <Label />
       .....
       <Label />
       <Label />
       </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

There are a large number of labels, so many that they go off the end of the screen.  But the screen won't scroll.  How can I make it scrollable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label /> 
            <Label /> 
            <Label /> 
            <Entry />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have Labels and they are pretty simple, why not use a ListView which has implicit scrolling? Otherwise Cole Xia is correct, wrap in a ScrollView